# 0 artifacts were found. and job configuration variables

Tags: artifactory, bamboo

I'm using `Artifacotry Genereic Deploy` task with `Bamboo` build server.
Is there a way to configure this task to yield out error if the task finds zero artifacts, `0 artifacts where found.`?

output from my log.

> 27-Feb-2018 11:21:25  Finished task 'Create artifactorySettings file' with result: Success
>   27-Feb-2018 11:21:26    Starting task 'Publish to artifactory' of type 'org.jfrog.bamboo.bamboo-artifactory-plugin:artifactoryGenericTask'
>   27-Feb-2018 11:21:26    Bamboo Artifactory Plugin version: 2.3.0
>   27-Feb-2018 11:21:27    For pattern: built/*.tgz 0 artifacts were found.

I find it missleading not to yield out error on `0 artifacts were found.`

Aslo when using `Job configuration` in the same task, can I add variables to the task, someting like this sudo code tries to acchive?

```
{
  "pattern": "/built/${myVar}",
  "location": "some/remote/location"
}
```

Comment: What would you consider a better behaviour then? would it suffice if the log would say 'Failure' instead of 'success' or would you expect the build to fail? Can you provide your use case?

Comment: At least a possibility to have the task to throw an error on zero artifacts found would help. What about the second question, can you elaborate on that? I find my self only achieving my desired behavior which is to distinguish between master and develop branch by creating a file in a previous task and use it in the generic task after. A possibility to insert variables would make this hack unnecessary.